# Images on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event

I make a game tic tac toe.Here i have image which i want to place in the box when i touch to that box.THe problem is that when i touch the screen then it show me image on the canvas but when i touch again to another box then the first image is disappear and new show in that box and pervoius is remove

```html
 public class caanvas extends View  {
    public Canvas canvas1=new Canvas();
        public float x_axis,y_axis;
        int height,width;
        Bitmap mFinalbitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cross);

       public  float firstcord=0f,secndcord=0f,thirdcord=0f,forthcord=0f,fifthcord=0f,sixcord=0f,sevencord=0f,eightcord=0f;
        public float widthborder=0f;
       public float h = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
       public  float w = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        public caanvas(Context context) {
            super(context);

            widthborder=w/72f;
            firstcord=w/2.88f;
            secndcord=w/1.5f;
            thirdcord=w/18f;
            forthcord=w/1.035f;
            fifthcord=h/4.2f;
            sixcord=h/2.46f;
            sevencord=h/1.63f;
            eightcord=h/1.28f;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas1=canvas;
            canvas.save();
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(widthborder);
            canvas.drawLine(firstcord, fifthcord, firstcord, eightcord, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(secndcord, fifthcord, secndcord, eightcord, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(thirdcord, sixcord, forthcord, sixcord, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(thirdcord, sevencord, forthcord, sevencord, paint);

            if(thirdcord<x_axis&&x_axis<firstcord&&fifthcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sixcord)//For A11 Box
            {
             width=(int)(firstcord-thirdcord);
             height=(int)(sixcord-fifthcord);
             Showimage();
            }
            else if(firstcord<x_axis&&x_axis<secndcord&&fifthcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sixcord)
        Showimage2();
            //else if(secndcord<x_axis&&x_axis<forthcord&&fifthcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sixcord)
       // Showimage();
           // else if(thirdcord<x_axis&&x_axis<firstcord&&sixcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sevencord)
           // Showimage();
            //else if(firstcord<x_axis&&x_axis<secndcord&&sixcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sevencord)
             //   Showimage();
           // else if (secndcord<x_axis&&x_axis<forthcord&&sixcord<y_axis&&y_axis<sevencord)
         //Showimage();
            //else if (thirdcord<x_axis&&x_axis<firstcord&&sevencord<y_axis&&y_axis<eightcord)
       // Showimage();
            //else  if (firstcord<x_axis&&x_axis<secndcord&&sevencord<y_axis&&y_axis<eightcord)
        //Showimage();
          //  else if(secndcord<x_axis&&x_axis<forthcord&&sevencord<y_axis&&y_axis<eightcord)
      //  Showimage();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            x_axis = ev.getX();
            y_axis = ev.getY();
            Log.i("Tag","Rana asad");
            switch (ev.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://avc

                    ;
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }


            return true;
        }

        public void Showimage()
        {

           mFinalbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mFinalbitmap, width, height, false);
            canvas1.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, thirdcord, fifthcord, null);
        }
        public  void Showimage2()
        {
            mFinalbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mFinalbitmap, width, height, false);
            canvas1.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, firstcord, fifthcord, null);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onDraw()` is supposed to draw the entire contents of your View at that moment. It is not cumulative; you have to draw everything again because what you drew the last time `onDraw()` was called is not kept. If you only draw the image in the last square you touched, then only that image will be shown.

This means you need to keep track of all the squares that have been touched and draw the image in each of those squares during `onDraw()`. Your touch event code should figure out which square the user is touching, mark that square as touched, and then `invalidate()`.